# I am not able to record the webrtc protocol using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have an android app in which we can do video call peers to peers using webrtc protocol. I want to perform performance testing of this app using jmeter but I am not able to record this. So guyz Please help me if anyone knows.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As it's evidenced by its name, JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) can record only [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) and [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) traffic, moreover I don't think you will be able to record and successfully replay WebRTC calls as they will differ from one virtual user to another.

If you have to load test your service using JMeter I would rather come up with [developing a plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) or using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/), the WebRTC client/peer libraries you can use are:

- [webrtc-java](https://github.com/devopvoid/webrtc-java)
- [gstreamer-java](https://github.com/gstreamer-java)